# jquery drag drop add class

Tags: jquery, html, draggable, droppable

I am trying to do this: When you drag the pink box into the drop area the pink box turn blue.

By adding a class or css in jquery.

code so far. So 'each' is pink and i want to add a class to this once is has been dropped in preview

```
$('.page').click(function(){
        $(this).draggable({
            revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
            cursor: "move"  
        });
    });

    $(".preview").droppable();
```

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: Could you not do this in CSS? Or do you for sure need the extra class for something else?

Answer (score 2):

in the callback of your droppable.drop function do the following:

```
$(ui.draggable).removeClass("pink").addClass("blue");
```

full code:

CSS

```
.pink {
    background: pink;
}

.blue {
    background: blue;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {
      $("#draggable").draggable();
      $("#droppable").droppable({
          drop: function (event, ui) {
              $(ui.draggable).removeClass("pink").addClass("blue");
          }
      });
  });
```

EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/vQs2L/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here's some example for orientation

```
function init() {
  $('#mydraggable').draggable();
  $('#mydroppable').droppable( {
    drop: handleDropEvent
  } );
}

function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {
   if(/*check that the dropped element is pink*/) {
  // $yourpinkbox.addClass("blueclass");
}

}
```